# Plone backup time stamps don't match system

Tags: backup, plone, plone-4.x

I am working on a development Plone 4.3.3 site with Zope 2.13.22 on Debian and noticed when I ran my backup using collective.recipe.backup that the backup time in the file name is 6 hours ahead of my system.

Example:
Backup name = 2014-08-06-17-08-15.fsz
System time (and write time according to properties) = 2014-08-06 11:08:15

I have checked multiple areas of Plone and they all match my system time. 
My buildout.cfg contains the correct Time Zone information.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this or how to correct it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your GMT +6? Maybe collective.recipe.backup use zope DateTime someway somewhere

Comment: My GMT is +6, same as Denver or Calgary. I thought the same as you with zope DateTime, but was unable to find any info/evidence along those lines.

Comment: Can you enhance your question pasting the relevant part of buildout configuration where you are setting Time Zone?

Comment: It makes sense to not have local time in the filename, because local time isn't unique (in regions that have daylight savings time). It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, this is how the backup script works.  Time values are always rendered in UTC, not server local time.  This allows for unambiguous ordering of backup files.

If you look at [the source of the repozo script](https://github.com/zopefoundation/ZODB/blob/4.0.1/src/ZODB/scripts/repozo.py#L368) used for backup you can see that the date portion of the filename always uses [time.gmtime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.gmtime) so this is not something you can change.

Comment: Thanks cewing. I missed that.